# wrapper для bootstap

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

[image: ***общий отступ***]

Подходит ли такая обертка для страницы реализованной через *bootstap*?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <main><!-- обертка в которой указан border и box-shadow для всей страницы-->
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <header><!-- тут начинается остальная часть страницы -->
                <nav>
                  <ul>
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                    <li>4</li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
              </header>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассказали,что для этого макета подойдет такой вид 
`

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">Logo</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">Description</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <nav>
            <a href=""></a>
            <a href=""></a>
            <a href=""></a>
            <a href=""></a>
            <a href=""></a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6"></div>
          <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <section>
            <h2>Heading</h2>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <section>
            <h2>Heading</h2>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <section>
            <h2>Heading</h2>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <section>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">

          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html> `
```